# I want to encrypt an entire password column in a table on a mysql database, using the salted hash method or aes encrypt method, how do i go about it?

Tags: mysql, hash, aes, mysql-workbench, salt

That is the image above, i need the final piece to complete the project. Can anyone help me with the code to encrypt the entire password column, using aes_encrypt method or salted hash method?

I tried creating a trigger using a code I saw on the site and it didn't work. The syntax was wrong. I need the password to be visible only to the user and in a case where the user forgets the password, it can be reset with minimal errors. If it is possible to salt the entire column, i would love to know how.

Comment: Never encrypt passwords, but hash them instead. Therefore, "salted hash" is the way to go, and "aes_encrypt" should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: "...I need the password to be visible only to the user..." -- that would be a big security hole. Why would you need something like that?

Comment: (edit) `in a case where the user forgets the password` That's what a [Forgot Password option](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244377/how-forgot-password-works) is for. You should never need to store or display plain text passwords.